# FTP server to show client progress

Tags: java, ftp

I have a situation where I need to show the progress of multiple FTP clients which are accessing the same file on a location X in FTP server. I need to show this progress from the server itself, not from the client. (The operation is initiated from the server like the server communicates the client the FTP site user name/password, file location and then the client does a health check of itself and starts a FTP get operation).

I know from the client there is a deterministic way of calculating the number of bytes downloaded with the actual file size so that it would be easy to show that on a percentage or time scale. But I was wondering waht would I do if I need the same capability from the FTP server itself.

Comment: Keep track of bytes transmitted and divide them by the bytes remaining to be transmitted.

Comment: `tick` is the only thing I know of on the server side, but I don't think it shows details.

Comment: in my case, the FTP server is on solaris, I guess it's provided by Solaris platform itself. So, should I think of writing a wrapper around that so that I can sniff the bytes being transmitted ? I am not sure if that's a viable option.

Comment: I have the same problem. Probably it's best to wrap the file InputStream and count the data. The challenge now is to find a server implementation which allows to manipulate the stream without rewriting huge parts of server code